# Jupyter does not show multiprocessed matplotlib plot until print

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I am dealing with a big dataset that I would like to plot in parallel to speed things up. I can easily create plots and save them to disk but they only show up in my JupyterLab notebook when I force a print inside each process. Is there any way to avoid the print?

```py
%matplotlib inline 

def task(args):
    i, path = args       
    print("WHY PYTHON WHY???")  # <-- plot will not be visible without this
    matplotlib.font_manager._get_font.cache_clear()  # necessary to reduce corruption artifacts
    values = range(10000)
    plt.figure(figsize=(40,10))
    plt.violinplot(values)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(path)
    return i

paths = [f"figs/{i}.png" for i in range(9)]

with Pool(10) as pool:
    for i in pool.imap(task, zip(range(9), paths)):
        pass
```

Comment: Similar problem here. I'm trying to plot dynamically from a multiprocessing system. It works fine out of jupyter. Adding a print in the middle also works for me.